# LatLng from Google Maps Polygon getPath()

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Based on the [Google Maps JavaScript API v3 documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon), `google.maps.Polygon` class's `getPath()` function returns an `MVCArray`. In a straightforward case, a Polygon's path can be a single array of `LatLngs` that are converted to the `MVCArray` type upon being passed into the google.maps.Polygon class's `setPath()` function.

The above case is what I'm dealing with currently. I pass in an array of `LatLngs`, and return (what I assume is) an `MVCObject` when I call `getPath()` on my Polygon object. My question is: How do I convert this `MVCObject` back into a single array of `LatLngs` that form the Polygon's shape? Is there some built in Google Maps API v3 way that I'm missing? I feel like there has to be some sort of obvious built in conversion function or something in the API that's eluding me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When you call `Polygon.getPath()`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon), the return is an `MVCArray`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MVCArray) of `LatLng` instances that represent the first path of the `Polygon`. You can directly get to the members of the `MVCAarray` in two ways:

1. Call `MVCAarray.getArray`, which will return the underlying JavaScript `Array` that contains `LatLng` members.
2. Use `MVCArray.getAt( index )`, which will return whatever is at that index in the `MVCArray` (a `LatLng` in this case). This provides you a way to setup a JavaScript `for` loop to iterate over the members of the array.

You can also indirectly work with the members of the `MVCArray` by using the `forEach(callback:function(*, number))` function. In this case, you must pass a callback function that accepts two parameters:

1. The actual member element of the `MVCArray`.
2. The array index where that element is located.

Comment: Is there a way to get LngLat instead of LatLong (geoJson coordinates)?

Answer (score 6):

```
    var polygonBounds = polygon.getPath();
    var bounds = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < polygonBounds.length; i++) {
          var point = {
            lat: polygonBounds.getAt(i).lat(),
            lng: polygonBounds.getAt(i).lng()
          };
          bounds.push(point);
     }
```

Comment: Could you explain why and how this code provides an answer to OP's question?

Comment: you can get all paths of polygon in json array with lat and lng