# Convert string to google maps paths

Tags: arrays, string, maps

I have string like this: `path1:[{lat:41.643606,lng:41.632819},{lat:41.641746,lng:41.633849},{lat:41.643799,lng:41.640887},{lat:41.645915,lng:41.639771}]`,

And i want to convert it to array for google maps paths.

Any ideas?

Comment: What system are you using, what have you already tried?

Comment: Without any information it is hard to answer your question. Have you googled? These two questions of SO come on top which might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760731/converting-string-of-coordinates-to-lat-long-array-for-google-maps-api-v3-return

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485806/latlng-from-google-maps-polygon-getpath

Comment: Sorry, am using javascrypt+php, and i have googled it but can't find anything, i have tried JSON.parse() but it says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token p` i have no idea what to do, thats why i'm asking here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascrypt eval() function helped.

```
path="path1:[{lat:41.643606,lng:41.632819},{lat:41.641746,lng:41.633849},{lat:41.643799,lng:41.640887},{lat:41.645915,lng:41.639771}],";

path=eval(path);
```

and then

```
polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: path,
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Only you can select an answer.  Please add an explanation of how you solved this problem to help the next person to need help.